# How do you implement a re-try-catch?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Try-catch is meant to help in the exception handling. This means somehow that it will help our system to be more robust: try to recover from an unexpected event.

We suspect something might happen when executing and instruction (sending a message), so it gets enclosed in the try. If that something nearly unexpected happens, we can do something: we write the catch. I don't think we called to just log the exception. I thing the catch block is meant to give us the opportunity of recovering from the error.

Now, let's say we recover from the error because we could fix what was wrong. It could be super nice to do a re-try:

```
try{ some_instruction(); }
catch (NearlyUnexpectedException e){
   fix_the_problem();
   retry;
}
```

This would quickly fall in the eternal loop, but let's say that the fix_the_problem returns true, then we retry. Given that there is no such thing in Java, how would YOU solve this problem? What would be your best design code for solving this?

This is like a philosophical question, given that I already know what I'm asking for is not directly supported by Java.

Comment: What kind of exception is that?

Comment: In deed, there are not many exception from which you can recover from. I admit my initial motivation was not a real exception, but way to avoid an if that will happen almost never: I try to `remove()` from a `java.util.Queue`, which thorws and `InvalidElementException` when the queue is empty. Instead of asking if it's empty, I sourround the actions in a try-catch (which under concurrency becomes compulsory even with the previous if). In such a case, in the `catch` block I would ask to refill the queue with more elements and then, retry. Voila.

Comment: I can see the usual way of doing this would be for DB access, if the connection has failed reconnect, if it fails then throw major exception otherwise retry the call again.  As has been said we could do it in a loop with a check at the bottom if(error<>0) then go back otherwise break;

Answer (score 412, accepted):

You need to enclose your `try-catch` inside a `while` loop like this: -

```
int count = 0;
int maxTries = 3;
while(true) {
    try {
        // Some Code
        // break out of loop, or return, on success
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        // handle exception
        if (++count == maxTries) throw e;
    }
}
```

I have taken `count` and `maxTries` to avoid running into an infinite loop, in case the exception keeps on occurring in your `try block`.

Comment: I thought in something like this at first, without the maxTries. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @AndresFarias.. Yeah, the most important point in this answer is to include a `maxTries`. Else it will run into an `infinite loop` if user continously gives wrong input, and hence will not exit. You're welcome though. :)

Comment: thank you for this - it just saved me from having to write some very gnarly code!

Comment: Is it possible adding Thread.sleep() function inside the catch at here. Because in some cases like waiting for page response in Selenium library that became critical. Thanks.

Comment: Same exception occurs if the exception is not handled even 3rd time

Comment: My implementation is:
try {  return true; } catch {  return false; }
and enclose a while loop: while ( !method() ) { method(); }

Comment: I used the while(true) with the scanner.nextInt(); and break; inside, but it kept looping without asking again.

Comment: Works great! For beginners: If you get positive infinite loop, check if You added "break;" at the end in "try" block.

Comment: how to do it with delay ?

Comment: change this. `if(++count >= maxTries)`

Answer (score 74):

Obligatory "enterprisy" solution:

```
public abstract class Operation {
    abstract public void doIt();
    public void handleException(Exception cause) {
        //default impl: do nothing, log the exception, etc.
    }
}

public class OperationHelper {
    public static void doWithRetry(int maxAttempts, Operation operation) {
        for (int count = 0; count < maxAttempts; count++) {
            try {
                operation.doIt();
                count = maxAttempts; //don't retry
            } catch (Exception e) {
                operation.handleException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to call:

```
OperationHelper.doWithRetry(5, new Operation() {
    @Override public void doIt() {
        //do some stuff
    }
    @Override public void handleException(Exception cause) {
        //recover from the Exception
    }
});
```

Comment: You should re-throw the exception if the last re-try fails, as done in the other answers given.

Comment: And may be a break instead of setting count to max attempts

Answer (score 47):

As usual, the best design depends on the particular circumstances. Usually though, I write something like:

```
for (int retries = 0;; retries++) {
    try {
        return doSomething();
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        if (retries < 6) {
            continue;
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, why not have the condition inside the for loop declaration like: for(int retries = 0; retries < 6; retries++) ??

Comment: Because I only want to throw in the last attempt, and therefore the catch block needs that condition, making the condition in the for redundant.

Comment: I do not think that `continue` is needed there.. And you can simply flip the if condition.

Answer (score 21):

You can use AOP and Java annotations from [jcabi-aspects](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-retryonfailure.html) (I'm a developer):

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 3, delay = 5)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

You could also use `@Loggable` and `@LogException` annotations.

Comment: is there a way to "fix" the error when attempt fails (do some adoptions that may fix the next attempt)? see question: `fix_the_problem();` in the catch block

Comment: Given the amount of open issues and the time passed for acknowledged bugs not being fixed, I would not rely on this library.

Answer (score 20):

Although `try/catch` into `while` is well-known and good strategy I want to suggest you recursive call:

```
void retry(int i, int limit) {
    try {

    } catch (SomeException e) {
        // handle exception
        if (i >= limit) {
            throw e;  // variant: wrap the exception, e.g. throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        retry(i++, limit);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is recursion better than a loop for this use case?

Comment: The stack trace may look a little odd on this one, because wouldn't it have `limit` count of the method being recursed?  As opposed to the loop version, which will throw at the 'original' level...

Comment: Sure looks elegant on paper but I'm not sure recursion is the right approach somehow.

Comment: I like recursion very much, although it has a problem too: if there are more instructions already performed this would perform them again. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I don't understand why recursion here too. Anyway, I think it could be simplified to: `void retry(int times) { (...) if (times==0) throw w; retry(times--);`

Comment: If an exception occurs within retry (when invoked from the catch recursively)  then it will not be handled by catch. So there should be nested try-catch in each catch handler, which is not elegant!

Comment: @bolaka, it will work. The excepion will be caught into the next rery invoked from catch. This is the point of recursion.

Comment: It is poor practice to use recursion as a substitute for mere iteration. Recursion is for use when you want to push and pop some data.

Comment: @EJP, you are absolutely right that using loop is better in general case. However if number of retries is limited by relatively small number using recursion IMHO makes code clearer.

Comment: It makes the code "clearer" at the cost of making a stack trace less clear.

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn, I respect your opinion :)

Comment: No, please don't use recursion. Terrible practice if the problem is not recursive.

Comment: Classic tail-end recursion that should be replaced with its iterative form

Answer (score 9):

Spring AOP and annotation based solution:

Usage (`@RetryOperation` is our custom annotation for the job):

```
@RetryOperation(retryCount = 1, waitSeconds = 10)
boolean someMethod() throws Exception {
}
```

We'll need two things to accomplish this: 1. an annotation interface, and 2. a spring aspect. Here's one way to implement these:

The Annotation Interface:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RetryOperation {
    int retryCount();
    int waitSeconds();
}
```

The Spring Aspect:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

@Aspect @Component 
public class RetryAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RetryAspect.class);

    @Around(value = "@annotation(RetryOperation)")
    public Object retryOperation(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        Object response = null;
        Method method = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
        RetryOperation annotation = method.getAnnotation(RetryOperation.class);
        int retryCount = annotation.retryCount();
        int waitSeconds = annotation.waitSeconds();
        boolean successful = false;

        do {
            try {
                response = joinPoint.proceed();
                successful = true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.info("Operation failed, retries remaining: {}", retryCount);
                retryCount--;
                if (retryCount < 0) {
                    throw ex;
                }
                if (waitSeconds > 0) {
                    LOGGER.info("Waiting for {} second(s) before next retry", waitSeconds);
                    Thread.sleep(waitSeconds * 1000l);
                }
            }
        } while (!successful);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a `while` loop with local `status` flag. Initialize the flag as `false` and set it to `true` when operation is successful e.g. below:

```
  boolean success  = false;
  while(!success){
     try{ 
         some_instruction(); 
         success = true;
     } catch (NearlyUnexpectedException e){
       fix_the_problem();
     }
  }
```

This will keep retrying until its successful.

If you want to retry only certain number of times then use a counter as well:

```
  boolean success  = false;
  int count = 0, MAX_TRIES = 10;
  while(!success && count++ < MAX_TRIES){
     try{ 
         some_instruction(); 
         success = true;
     } catch (NearlyUnexpectedException e){
       fix_the_problem();
     }
  }
  if(!success){
    //It wasn't successful after 10 retries
  }
```

This will try max 10 times if not successful until then an will exit if its successful before hand.

Comment: Rather than checking for `!success` in your while, you can just break out of while when success is true.

Comment: @RohitJain: It looks more clean to me.

Comment: @YogendraSingh.. Strange. as you are not modifying your `success` anywhere in your `catch`. So it seems redundant to check for it, on every run of `catch`.

Comment: @RohitJain: Catch is just correcting the data. It will go back and run the statement again. If successful, it will modify the `success`. Try it out.

Answer (score 6):

Most of these answers are essentially the same. Mine is also, but this is the form I like

```
boolean completed = false;
Throwable lastException = null;
for (int tryCount=0; tryCount < config.MAX_SOME_OPERATION_RETRIES; tryCount++)
{
    try {
        completed = some_operation();
        break;
    }
    catch (UnlikelyException e) {
        lastException = e;
        fix_the_problem();
    }
}
if (!completed) {
    reportError(lastException);
}
```

Comment: One drawback is that you also call `fix_the_problem` after the last attempt. That *could* be a costly operation and could waste some time.

Comment: @JoachimSauer True. You could `if (tryCount < max) fix()` -- but this is the format of a general approach; the details would depend on a specific case. There's also a guava based [Retryer](http://code.google.com/p/google-guava-retryer/) I've been looking at.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but a solution is still relevant. Here is my generic solution in Java 8 without using any third party library:

```
public interface RetryConsumer<T> {
    T evaluate() throws Throwable;
}
public interface RetryPredicate<T> {
    boolean shouldRetry(T t);
}
public class RetryOperation<T> {
    private RetryConsumer<T> retryConsumer;
    private int noOfRetry;
    private int delayInterval;
    private TimeUnit timeUnit;
    private RetryPredicate<T> retryPredicate;
    private List<Class<? extends Throwable>> exceptionList;

    public static class OperationBuilder<T> {
        private RetryConsumer<T> iRetryConsumer;
        private int iNoOfRetry;
        private int iDelayInterval;
        private TimeUnit iTimeUnit;
        private RetryPredicate<T> iRetryPredicate;
        private Class<? extends Throwable>[] exceptionClasses;

        private OperationBuilder() {
        }

        public OperationBuilder<T> retryConsumer(final RetryConsumer<T> retryConsumer) {
            this.iRetryConsumer = retryConsumer;
            return this;
        }

        public OperationBuilder<T> noOfRetry(final int noOfRetry) {
            this.iNoOfRetry = noOfRetry;
            return this;
        }

        public OperationBuilder<T> delayInterval(final int delayInterval, final TimeUnit timeUnit) {
            this.iDelayInterval = delayInterval;
            this.iTimeUnit = timeUnit;
            return this;
        }

        public OperationBuilder<T> retryPredicate(final RetryPredicate<T> retryPredicate) {
            this.iRetryPredicate = retryPredicate;
            return this;
        }

        @SafeVarargs
        public final OperationBuilder<T> retryOn(final Class<? extends Throwable>... exceptionClasses) {
            this.exceptionClasses = exceptionClasses;
            return this;
        }

        public RetryOperation<T> build() {
            if (Objects.isNull(iRetryConsumer)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("'#retryConsumer:RetryConsumer<T>' not set");
            }

            List<Class<? extends Throwable>> exceptionList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (Objects.nonNull(exceptionClasses) && exceptionClasses.length > 0) {
                exceptionList = Arrays.asList(exceptionClasses);
            }
            iNoOfRetry = iNoOfRetry == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            iTimeUnit = Objects.isNull(iTimeUnit) ? TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS : iTimeUnit;
            return new RetryOperation<>(iRetryConsumer, iNoOfRetry, iDelayInterval, iTimeUnit, iRetryPredicate, exceptionList);
        }
    }

    public static <T> OperationBuilder<T> newBuilder() {
        return new OperationBuilder<>();
    }

    private RetryOperation(RetryConsumer<T> retryConsumer, int noOfRetry, int delayInterval, TimeUnit timeUnit,
                           RetryPredicate<T> retryPredicate, List<Class<? extends Throwable>> exceptionList) {
        this.retryConsumer = retryConsumer;
        this.noOfRetry = noOfRetry;
        this.delayInterval = delayInterval;
        this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
        this.retryPredicate = retryPredicate;
        this.exceptionList = exceptionList;
    }

    public T retry() throws Throwable {
        T result = null;
        int retries = 0;
        while (retries < noOfRetry) {
            try {
                result = retryConsumer.evaluate();
                if (Objects.nonNull(retryPredicate)) {
                    boolean shouldItRetry = retryPredicate.shouldRetry(result);
                    if (shouldItRetry) {
                        retries = increaseRetryCountAndSleep(retries);
                    } else {
                        return result;
                    }
                } else {
                    // no retry condition defined, no exception thrown. This is the desired result.
                    return result;
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                retries = handleException(retries, e);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int handleException(int retries, Throwable e) throws Throwable {
        if (exceptionList.contains(e.getClass()) || (exceptionList.isEmpty())) {
            // exception is excepted, continue retry.
            retries = increaseRetryCountAndSleep(retries);
            if (retries == noOfRetry) {
                // evaluation is throwing exception, no more retry left. Throw it.
                throw e;
            }
        } else {
            // unexpected exception, no retry required. Throw it.
            throw e;
        }
        return retries;
    }

    private int increaseRetryCountAndSleep(int retries) {
        retries++;
        if (retries < noOfRetry && delayInterval > 0) {
            try {
                timeUnit.sleep(delayInterval);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        return retries;
    }
}
```

Let's have a test case like:

```
@Test
public void withPredicateAndException() {
    AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger();
    try {
        Integer result = RetryOperation.<Integer>newBuilder()
                .retryConsumer(() -> {
                    int i = integer.incrementAndGet();
                    if (i % 2 == 1) {
                        throw new NumberFormatException("Very odd exception");
                    } else {
                        return i;
                    }
                })
                .noOfRetry(10)
                .delayInterval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .retryPredicate(value -> value <= 6)
                .retryOn(NumberFormatException.class, EOFException.class)
                .build()
                .retry();
        Assert.assertEquals(8, result.intValue());
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice idea, a builder fro that!

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to solve the issue would be to wrap the try/catch in a while loop and maintain a count. This way you could prevent an infinite loop by checking a count against some other variable while maintaining a log of your failures. It isn't the most exquisite solution, but it would work.

Answer (score 2):

In case it's useful, a couple more options to consider, all thrown together (stopfile instead of retries, sleep, continue larger loop) all possibly helpful.

```
 bigLoop:
 while(!stopFileExists()) {
    try {
      // do work
      break;
    }
    catch (ExpectedExceptionType e) {

       // could sleep in here, too.

       // another option would be to "restart" some bigger loop, like
       continue bigLoop;
    }
    // ... more work
}
```

Comment: Down voters please leave comments as to why, thanks!

Comment: This is a sheer ignorance to downvote and not cite a reason.

Comment: sleeping there is not obvious since the while loop wouldn't wait

Answer (score 2):

If not all exceptions warrant a retry, only some. And if at least one try has to be made, Here is an alternative utility method:

```java
void runWithRetry(Runnable runnable, Class<Exception> exClass, int maxRetries) {
        Exception err = null;
        do {
            maxRetries--;
            try {
                runnable.run();
                err = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if(exClass.isAssignableFrom(e.getClass())){
                    err = e;
                }else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        } while (err != null && maxRetries > 0);

        if (err != null) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```java
    runWithRetry(() -> {
       // do something
    }, TimeoutException.class, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Production ready code:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Operation {

    void doCall() throws IOException;

    default void handleException(Exception e) {
      //Your custom default implementation     
    }


public class OperationHelper {
    public static void doWithRetry(int maxAttempts, Operation operation) {

        for (int count = 0; count <= maxAttempts; count++) {
            try {
                operation.doCall();
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (count == maxAttempts) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                } else {
                    operation.handleException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage with default implementation in code:

```
OperationHelper.doWithRetry(10,
() -> //do your job );
```

Usage when custom exception handle is needed:

```
OperationHelper.doWithRetry(10, new Operation() {
    @Override public void doIt() {
        //do some stuff
    }
    @Override public void handleException(Exception cause) {
        //recover from the Exception
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All a Try-Catch does is allow your program to fail gracefully.  In a catch statement, you generally try to log the error, and maybe roll back changes if you need to.

```
bool finished = false;

while(finished == false)
{
    try
    {
        //your code here
        finished = true
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
        log.error("there was an error, ex");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean as opposed to `(!finished)`?

Comment: @RohitJain  it looks too much like `while(finished)`.  I prefer to use the more verbose version.

Comment: How on earth does `while(!finished)` look like `while (finished)`??

Comment: @Rohit Because it's only one character different. They all get compiled down to the same thing. In C#, I use a String extension method `IsPopulated()` which just returns `!IsNullOrEmpty()` to ensure that my intent is understood by all developers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a do-while to design re-try block.

```
boolean successful = false;
int maxTries = 3;
do{
  try {
    something();
    success = true;
  } catch(Me ifUCan) {
    maxTries--;
  }
} while (!successful || maxTries > 0)
```

Comment: The code should throw the original exception if unsuccessfull

Answer (score 1):

Here a reusable and more generic approach for Java 8+ that does not require external libraries:

```
public interface IUnreliable<T extends Exception>
{
    void tryRun ( ) throws T;
}

public static <T extends Exception> void retry (int retryCount, IUnreliable<T> runnable) throws T {
    for (int retries = 0;; retries++) {
        try {
            runnable.tryRun();
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (retries < retryCount) {
                continue;
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Test
public void demo() throws IOException {
    retry(3, () -> {
        new File("/tmp/test.txt").createNewFile();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/bnsd55/RetryCatch

Example:

```
RetryCatch retryCatchSyncRunnable = new RetryCatch();
        retryCatchSyncRunnable
                // For infinite retry times, just remove this row
                .retryCount(3)
                // For retrying on all exceptions, just remove this row
                .retryOn(ArithmeticException.class, IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
                .onSuccess(() -> System.out.println("Success, There is no result because this is a runnable."))
                .onRetry((retryCount, e) -> System.out.println("Retry count: " + retryCount + ", Exception message: " + e.getMessage()))
                .onFailure(e -> System.out.println("Failure: Exception message: " + e.getMessage()))
                .run(new ExampleRunnable());
```

Instead of `new ExampleRunnable()` you can pass your own anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try using springs @Retryable annotation , the below method will retry for 3 attempts when RuntimeException occurs

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts=3,value= {RuntimeException.class},backoff = @Backoff(delay = 500))
public void checkSpringRetry(String str) {
    if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(str, "R")) {
        LOGGER.info("Inside retry.....!!");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Edit:
unit test

```
@Test
public void testCheckSpringRetry() {
    try {
        yourClass.checkSpringRetry("R");
        fail("Expected RuntimeException, but it did not occur.");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // This is expected, and the test will pass.
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you unit test this?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying @ach's previous solution into one file and using functional interfaces.

```
public class OperationHelper {

    public static void doWithRetry(int maxAttempts, Runnable operation, Consumer<Exception> handle) {
        for (int count = 0; count < maxAttempts; count++) {
            try {
                operation.run();
                count = maxAttempts; //don't retry
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handle.accept(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll upvote if you show an example of it in use

Answer (score 1):

simple

```
int MAX = 3;

int count = 0;
while (true) {
    try {
        ...

        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (count++ < MAX) {
            continue;
        }

        ...
        
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://onlinegdb.com/a-7RsL1Gh

```
    public void doSomething() throws Exception{
      final int MAX_TRIES = 10;
      int count = 0;
      
      while(count++ < MAX_TRIES){
         try{ 
            System.out.println("trying");
            causeIssue(count); // throws error/exception till count 2
            System.out.println("trying successful");
            break; // break on success
         } catch (Exception e){
           System.out.println("caught, logging Exception:" + count);
         } catch (Error e){
           System.out.println("caught, logging Error:" + count);
         }
      }
    }
```

Output:

```
trying
caught, logging Error:1
trying
caught, logging Error:2
trying
trying successful
```

Comment: Is there some shortcoming to this, since it's so much simpler than the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

I know there are already many similar answers here, and mine is not much different, but I will post it anyway because it deals with a specific case/issue.

When dealing with the `facebook Graph API` in `PHP` you sometimes get an error, but immediately re-trying the same thing will give a positive result (for various *magical* Internet reasons that are beyond the scope of this question). In this case there is no need to *fix* any error, but to simply try again because there was some kind of "facebook error".

This code is used immediately after creating a facebook session:

```
//try more than once because sometimes "facebook error"
$attempt = 3;
while($attempt-- > 0)
{
    // To validate the session:
    try 
    {
        $facebook_session->validate();
        $attempt = 0;
    } 
    catch (Facebook\FacebookRequestException $ex)
    {
        // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
        if($attempt <= 0){ echo $ex->getMessage(); }
    } 
    catch (\Exception $ex) 
    {
        // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
        if($attempt <= 0){ echo $ex->getMessage(); }
    }
}
```

Also, by having the `for` loop count down to zero (`$attempt--`) it makes it pretty easy to change the number of attempts in the future.

Answer (score 0):

following is my solution with very simple approach!

```
               while (true) {
                    try {
                        /// Statement what may cause an error;
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
```

Comment: please look at @Rohit Jain answer which is more specific and not an infinite loop in negative cases.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is the "Professional" way to do it and i'm not entirely sure if it works for everything.

```
boolean gotError = false;

do {
    try {
        // Code You're Trying
    } catch ( FileNotFoundException ex ) {
        // Exception
        gotError = true;
    }
} while ( gotError = true );
```

Comment: I think the best approach is `do-while`, even it is the one of the rare convenient purpose of `do-while` loop. Only thing you may want to edit while parentheses as `while ( gotError );`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tusharmndr/retry-function-wrapper/tree/master/src/main/java/io

```
int MAX_RETRY = 3; 
RetryUtil.<Boolean>retry(MAX_RETRY,() -> {
    //Function to retry
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the remaining solutions is that, the correspondent function tries continuously without a time interval in-between, thus over flooding the stack.

Why not just `try`ing only every second and *ad eternum*?

Here a solution using `setTimeout` and a recursive function:

```js
(function(){
  try{
    Run(); //tries for the 1st time, but Run() as function is not yet defined
  }
  catch(e){
    (function retry(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        try{
          console.log("trying...");
          Run();
          console.log("success!");
        }
        catch(e){
          retry(); //calls recursively
        }
      }, 1000); //tries every second
    }());
  }
})();



//after 5 seconds, defines Run as a global function
var Run;
setTimeout(function(){
  Run = function(){};
}, 5000);
```

Replace the function `Run()` by the function or code that you'd like to re`try` every second.

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet execute some code snippet. If you got any error while executing the code snippet, sleep for M milliseconds and retry. Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2020/04/implement-re-try-catch.html).

```
public void retryAndExecuteErrorProneCode(int noOfTimesToRetry, CodeSnippet codeSnippet, int sleepTimeInMillis)
  throws InterruptedException {

 int currentExecutionCount = 0;
 boolean codeExecuted = false;

 while (currentExecutionCount < noOfTimesToRetry) {
  try {
   codeSnippet.errorProneCode();
   System.out.println("Code executed successfully!!!!");
   codeExecuted = true;
   break;
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // Retry after 100 milliseconds
   TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTimeInMillis);
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  } finally {
   currentExecutionCount++;
  }
 }

 if (!codeExecuted)
  throw new RuntimeException("Can't execute the code within given retries : " + noOfTimesToRetry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution similar to some others can wrap a function, but allows you to get the functions return value, if it suceeds.

```
    /**
     * Wraps a function with retry logic allowing exceptions to be caught and retires made.
     *
     * @param function the function to retry
     * @param maxRetries maximum number of retires before failing
     * @param delay time to wait between each retry
     * @param allowedExceptionTypes exception types where if caught a retry will be performed
     * @param <V> return type of the function
     * @return the value returned by the function if successful
     * @throws Exception Either an unexpected exception from the function or a {@link RuntimeException} if maxRetries is exceeded
     */
    @SafeVarargs
    public static <V> V runWithRetriesAndDelay(Callable<V> function, int maxRetries, Duration delay, Class<? extends Exception>... allowedExceptionTypes) throws Exception {
        final Set<Class<? extends Exception>> exceptions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(allowedExceptionTypes));
        for(int i = 1; i <= maxRetries; i++) {
            try {
                return function.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if(exceptions.contains(e.getClass())){
                    // An exception of an expected type
                    System.out.println("Attempt [" + i + "/" + maxRetries + "] Caught exception [" + e.getClass() + "]");
                    // Pause for the delay time
                    Thread.sleep(delay.toMillis());
                }else {
                    // An unexpected exception type
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(maxRetries + " retries exceeded");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Solution allows you to configure a reusable functionality for retrying  based on certain exception without using any external libraries

// Create a Function that suits your need .

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowableBiFunction<U,T,R> {
    R apply(U u ,T t) throws Exception;
}
```

//Here's the crux of the solution

```
public interface ExceptionRetryable<T, U, R> {
    
 int getRetries();
   
 List<Class<? extends Exception>> getRetryableExceptions();

    default R execute(ThrowableBiFunction<T, U, R> function, T t, U u) throws Exception {
        int numberOfRetries = getRetries();
        return execute(function, t, u, numberOfRetries);
    }

    default R execute(ThrowableBiFunction<T, U, R> function, T t, U u, int retryCount) throws Exception {
        try {
            log.info(" Attempting to execute ExceptionRetryable#execute ,Number of remaining retries {} ",retryCount);
            return function.apply(t, u);
        } catch (Exception e) {

           log.info(" error occurred in ExceptionRetryable#execute",e);
            if (retryCount == 0)
                throw e;
            for (Class exp : getRetryableExceptions()) {
                if (e.getClass() == exp) {
                   return execute(function, t, u, retryCount - 1);
                }
            }
            throw e;
        }

    }
}
```

// create an implementation for exception retryable

```
public class TestRetryable implements ExceptionRetryable<String, String, List<String>> {
    @Override
    public int getRetries() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends Exception>> getRetryableExceptions() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Exception1().getClass(), new Exception2().getClass());
        ;
    }
}
```

// Finally create a ThrowableBiFunction that encapsulates that piece of code that needs to be retried on exception  and an instance of ExceptionRetryable

```
 TestRetryable retryable = new TestRetryable();
    ThrowableBiFunction<Integer,Long, String> testRetrablefcn = { i, l ->
           // your code goes here
};
    Integer i = 0;
    Long l = 1l;
      String output = testRetrablefcn.execute(testRetrablefcn,i,l);
```