# "Best Practice" for retrying a try / catch statement

Tags: java

given:

```
public void connect() {
    try {
        connect_to_server();
    } catch (ServerUnavailableException ex){
        System.out.print("server unavailable");
    }
}
```

I would like to *try*, and retry, connecting to the server 3 times before giving up.

I *could* put the entire try/catch in, say, a `for` loop, but would this fit with Java's 'Best Practices'. From what I recall on the topic, this would be a misuse of `try/catch` statements. Then again, I could be entirely wrong. What do you think?

Comment: It would be better if you implement `connect_to_server()` to throw exception after failing for the third time.

Also, method name as `connectToServer()` is convention in java.

Comment: Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/13239999/1433665

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you implement `connect_to_server()` to throw exception after failing for the third time.

Also, method name as `connectToServer()` is convention in java.