# How to repeat a "request" until success? NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, timeout, httpwebrequest

I checked a few thread in StackOverflow, but nothing works for me.
I have this request call and I need it to try to send the request until it succeed (but if it fails, it has to wait at least 3 seconds):

```
sortingKeywords.sortVerifiedPhrase = function(phrase) {

    var URL = "an API URL"+phrase; //<== Obviously that in my program it has an actual API URL
    request(URL, function(error, response, body) {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var keyword = JSON.parse(body);
            if(sortingKeywords.isKeyMeetRequirements(keyword)){ //Check if the data is up to a certain criteria
                sortingKeywords.addKeyToKeywordsCollection(keyword); //Adding to the DB
            } else {
                console.log("doesn't meet rquirement");
            }
        } else {
            console.log(phrase);
            console.log("Error: "+ error);
        }

    });
};
```

Here's the weird part, if I call the same phrases in a row from the browser, it works almost without errors (it usually states: rate limit time esceeded).

Appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694467/promises-repeat-operation-until-it-succeeds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working program that I've written for this request. It sends the request via a function, if the request fails, it returns `error` handler and calls the function again.

If the function succeeds the program returns a promise and quits executing.

NOTE: if you enter an invalid url the programs exits right away, that's something that's have to do with `request` module, which I like to be honest. It lets you know that you have an invalid url. So you must include `https://` or `http://` in the url

```
var request = require('request');

var myReq;
//our request function
function sendTheReq(){
  myReq = request.get({
    url: 'http://www.google.com/',
    json: true
    }, (err, res, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error:', err)
    } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
      console.log('Status:', res.statusCode)
    } else {
      // data is already parsed as JSON:
      //console.log(data);
    }
  })
}

sendTheReq();

//promise function
function resolveWhenDone(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    myReq.on('end', function(){
      resolve(x)
    })
    myReq.on('error', function(err){
      console.log('there was an error:  ---Trying again');
      sendTheReq();  //sending the request again
      f1();          //starting the promise again
    })
  });
}

//success handler
async function f1() {
  var x = await resolveWhenDone(100);
  if(x == 100){
      console.log("request has been completed");
      //handle other stuff
  }
}

f1();
```

Answer (score 0):

On error run this code

`setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);`

See this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Also you can make a code like this

var func1 = function(){};
`setTimeout(func1, 3000);`