# In Exception handling maximum how many times we apply Nested try-catch in C#

Tags: c#

In Exception handling **maximum how many times we apply Nested try-catch** in C#
Unable to find answer?

Comment: Is this an academic question? Just curious what for you need this information. I think the compiler won't complain about 10 nested `try/catch` blocks, but surely everyone reading that code will.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239972/how-do-you-implement-a-re-try-catch

may be you are looking out for this

Comment: This not an academic question? but we should know that.
Someone asked that question to me.

Comment: I would say: as many times as the c# file still fits in memory, as many times are you are able to write (and execute and test) in a lifetime, as many times as you are able to find a useful example for it.

Comment: Questions like these have a standard answer: if you need to know then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Who say's.. its not wrong question. Right now I'm using nesting  at 5 levels..

Comment: 5 levels is wrong. Exception handling is not a mechanism that should be used to control the application flow. If you do that you have fundamentally misunderstood what exceptions are.

Comment: @RohitMane That code doesn't say anything about why you *need* this. You could (and probably should) implement it without nesting.

Comment: Really I've implemented code for some reasons...
Used try-catch in this way..
            try
            {  }
            catch ()
            {  try
                {  }
                catch ()
                { try
                    {}
                    catch ()
                    {...

                    }
                }

Comment: @RohitMane Yes, the way you do it you use exceptions to control program flow. That is not how they should be used. I have myself nested `try`-blocks in the **`finally`** block to catch exceptions during cleanup.

Comment: **Why** should this be **opinion based**???? This question is never ever opinion based!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding (no proofs, only thoughts) it's not limited. I haven't said *unlimited*, but what there is no `MaxNesting` property or constant somewhere.

`try/catch/finally` is a `C#` construction compiled into IL. The question is basically equal to

> how deep can be [insert keyword] nesting

E.g.: `switch`, `if`, `foreach`, etc.

Have you heard ever about maximum nesting of those? I don't think so.

There can be just one `try/catch` in the recursive method calling itself inside `try`. Does `try` brings any limitations by itself? Yes, as this obviously have to use more memory to hold address of `catch` somewhere. Can you say the number? Nope, it depends on available memory.

Comment: May be but I'm exited for perfect answer..

Comment: Let's wait for one ;)

Answer (score 2):

There can not be a limit if you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) carefully, which says that a `try` block surrounds guarded code that potentially throws an exception. Same goes for the `catch` block, which surrounds the code to execute when an exception occurs and the `finally` block.

As a `try-catch-finally` block is itself by definition a code block, this definition is recursive, so any `try` block can surround a `try-catch-finally` block, any `catch` and `finally` block can, too.

The only limits are readability and memory.

> but we should know that.

Why? What advantage do you gain or expect from that information? I'm very much with what @HansPassant said in the comments...

By the way: Nothing keeps you from writing a small test application that generates a C# file with a given maximum number of nesting levels, which you then try to compile. If you find a maximum, look at the source file and ask yourself if this is still readable.

Comment: Can you help me how to handle above situation in Exception Handling.
May be the way I've chosen is wrong..

Comment: Well, the code you provided in the comments doesn't say much about what you actually *do*. It just shows you have other `try-catch` blocks in the `catch` block. Maybe if you extended your question to show an example of what you do you'd get suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: @RohitMane Was this asked in an interview? I have had dumb interviewers ask me this and piss me off straightaway. Unless there was a limit of say 5-6 catch blocks, it will not come into picture in real life ever. But still dumb interviewers ask questions like this a lot.