# retry catch java with still image

Tags: java, image, try-catch

I have a while loop. In the while loop there is a try catch.
In the try a get every 2 seconds the still image from an IP camera.

But somethime i get an exception because the code doesn't get all the packets ..
Now i want that when i get the exception , that my code retry the try in my code ..

Can you help me ?

```
while(true){

           Image image = null;
  try {

                String path = "http://10.13.8.14/media/cam0/still.jpg?res=800";

                URL url = new URL(path);
                image = ImageIO.read(url);
                Thread.sleep(2000);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "image niet in orde");
            }
            ImageIcon lic = new ImageIcon(image);
            label.setIcon(lic);

        }
```

Comment: Just one comment after looking at your code.

Look like you got one infinite loop, set up a break somewhere.

Comment: that is the meaning , i want every 2 secons a new image from my IP camera url

Comment: Be sure that you won't end up in out of memory...

Comment: You should put your Try and catch block in a infinite while loop. And in try give a terminating condition to break out of the loop. Hence it will keep on calling the try until the terminating condition is met after catching the exception

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in a method and call the method for both the calls.

```
public void tryBlock() throws Exception{
        Image image=null;
        String path = "http://10.13.8.14/media/cam0/still.jpg?res=800";
        URL url = new URL(path);
        image = ImageIO.read(url);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

keep calling this method until no Exception is thrown

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: keep calling this method until no Exception is thrown

Comment: You should put your Try and catch block in a infinite while loop. And in try block give a terminating condition to break out of the loop. Hence it will keep on calling the try block until the terminating condition is met after catching the exception. Tell me if it works

Comment: Have a look at this also :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239972/how-do-you-implement-a-re-try-catch