# Implement Global Resilience with Custom Exception

Tags: java, sap-cloud-sdk

I am interacting with the SAP Business One Service Layer using code generated via the SAP Cloud SDK.

One thing that must be accounted for with the Service Layer is the potential for deadlocks in the database. The general recommendation is to retry the operation if a deadlock is detected.

I am wondering if there is a way to elegantly wrap all calls made by the SAP Cloud SDK with a resilience decorator to retry in the case of a deadlock.

The current logic for checking for a deadlock is to check the ODataCode:

```
public boolean checkIfDeadlockError(Throwable serviceLayerThrowable){

        if (serviceLayerThrowable instanceof ODataServiceErrorException serviceErrorException) {
            return serviceErrorException.getOdataError().getODataCode().equals("-2038");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Right now I am having to ensure I wrap every single call with the same resilience decorator, which is tedious.

Comment: Yes - wrap the entire use of the SDK, and use that wrapper throughout the rest of your code.  Along with centralizing the SDK logic which moves the retry logic to one place, it also avoids exposing the SDK to the rest of the app.  So when the SDK changes, only the wrapper code changes.

Comment: @AndrewS How would you recommend doing that though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAP Cloud SDK allows you to specify a
`retryOnExceptionPredicate(Predicate<Throwable> retryOnExceptionPredicate)` with the [RetryConfiguration](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/java-api/v5/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/resilience/ResilienceConfiguration.RetryConfiguration.html). With that you can specify in which cases an exception should be retried.

For example, you could do an `instanceof` check like so: `var predicate = e -> e instanceof IllegalArgumentException`.

Alternatively, you could catch the relevant exception within your code and return some other representation of the result.

Comment: Is there a way to apply that RetryConfiguration to all calls or is it necessary to wrap all calls like the documentation describes? `ResilienceDecorator.executeSupplier(() -> operation(), configuration1);`

Comment: What do you mean with "all calls"? How would the resilience know, around which method invocations exactly it should be applied? No, I think you have to wrap it for each distinct execution. If you want you can make that a bit more convenient by building your own annotation or build a Spring Aspect. For the latter I uploaded an example here: https://gist.github.com/MatKuhr/dec64c830c6144d2284a58bf3af3d851

Answer (score 0):

Adding as answer to clarify comment...

So given some class `SapBusinessOneSdk`, which is a specific implementation, wrap it on your own code.  For example:

```
import sap.business.one.SapBusinessOneSdk;  // only class that knows about the specific implementation

public class SapService {
    private final SapBusinessOneClient client; // assuming this is thread-safe

    // assuming some dependency injection (DI) to configure
    public SapService(SapConfig config) {
        SapBusinessOneSdk.clientBuilder()
            .connectionString(config.getConnectionString())
            .build();
    }

    public MyResponse doSomething(MyRequest request) {
       try {
           // map app domain request to SDK request
           var sdkRequest = SapBusinessOneSdk.requestBuilder()
               .id(request.getId())
               ...
               .build();


               // add retry here
               // old school: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239972/how-do-you-implement-a-re-try-catch
               var response = client.thisIsSoSappy(sdkRequest);

               // map response to app specific response
               return MyResponse.builder().
               .message(response.getMessage())
               .build();

           } catch(Exception e) {
              // avoid rest of app being aware of the specific SDK exception classes
              throw new AppSpecificException(..., e);  
           }          
      }
  }
```

Then use `SapService` anywhere that's needed in the other service layer classes.  For example:

```
 public class SomeAppService {
     private final SapService sap;

     // assuming DI to inject the service
     public SomeAppService(SapService sap) {
        this.sap = sap;
     }

     public void doSomethingThatInvolvesSap(BusinessContext context) {
         // map context to a request
         var request = MyRequest.builder()...build();

        // call SAP, via the wrapper
        var response = sap.doSomething(request);

       // do something with the response...
   }
}
```

Note that if the SDK changes (or even a complete replacement to another SAP provider), the only class that has to change is `SapService`.