# how to convert two similar methods in one?

Tags: java, generics, types

How can I make one method generic method `doRetry` out of these two methods `doRetryA` and `doRetryB` in Java where moth boths execute similar code but differs in `func1` and func2 calls where func1 and `func2` take same number of arguments and these arguments are same types but func1 and `func2` differs in functionalities but return same type?

```
SomeType foo = someEnum.enumValue;


private SomeType def doRetryA() {
    for(int attempt=0; attempt<retries; attempt++) {
        foo = func1(a, b);
    return foo;
}

private SomeType def doRetryB() {
    for(int attempt=0; attempt<retries; attempt++) {
        foo = func2(a, b);
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: Just take the function as an argument, a bi-function would do it.

Comment: `doRetry(BiFunction<TypeOfA, TypeOfB, SomeType> func) { ... foo = func.apply(a, b); ... }`. Then you can call it as `doRetry(this::func1);` or `doRetry(this::func2);`

Comment: func1 and func2 both  throws IOException, InterruptedException and now doRetry complains about unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @darkman define `interface ThrowingBiFunction`, which has a single method that is declared to throw the checked exceptions.

Comment: You didn't specify that so we couldn't know. That's why it's important to include all important information in your question

Comment: I realize and agree with you. BiFunction helps here but I did not know throwing exeption is important part here.

Comment: @AndyTurner how could I use this interface ThrowingBiFunction? I am not Java native.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: how to handle retries without copy-paste code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539845/java-how-to-handle-retries-without-copy-paste-code)

Comment: nah, I am using java 11 HttpClient and manualy solving retries with simple for loop

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface like so:

```
interface ThrowingBiFunction<A, B, C> {
  C apply(A a, B b) throws IOException, InterruptedException;
}
```

then accept an instance of this in your method:

```
private FooType doRetry(ThrowingBiFunction<AType, BType, FooType> func) {
    for(int attempt=0; attempt<retries; attempt++) {
        foo = func.apply(a, b);
    return foo;
}
```

I don't know the types of `a`, `b` or `foo`. Perhaps they are the same in both cases, perhaps they're not. If they're not the same, add some type parameters, e.g.

```
private <AType, BType, FooType> FooType doRetry(ThrowingBiFunction<AType, BType, FooType> func) {
```

Then invoke:

```
doRetry((a, b) -> func1(a, b));  // Or doRetry(this::func1) or similar.
doRetry((a, b) -> func2(a, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the function type you want using a string variable as something like this...

```
SomeType foo = someEnum.enumValue;

private SomeType def doRetry(String funcType) {
    for (int attempt=0; attempt<retries; attempt++) {
        if (funcType.equals("ONE")) {
            foo = func1(a, b);
        } else if (funcType.equals("TWO")) {
            foo = func2(a, b);
        }
    }
    return foo;
}

//function call
doRetry("ONE");
```